# Error while running prngd: Failed to execl

Tags: sshd, execl

In my linux embedded device, I run prngd in the following way:

```
prngd /var/run/egd-pool
```

In the system log I am getting the followiong errors:

```
192.168.8.195.34453:<29>Jan  1 00:04:49 prngd[132]: prngd 0.9.29 (12 Jul 2004) started up for user root

192.168.8.195.34453:<29>Jan  1 00:04:49 prngd[132]: have 7 out of 1024 filedescriptors open

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:50 prngd[147]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/w, w, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:50 prngd[149]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/last, last, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:50 prngd[150]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/lastlog, lastlog, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:50 prngd[153]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/vmstat, vmstat, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:50 prngd[155]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/ipcs, ipcs, -a, , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:51 prngd[173]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/w, w, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:51 prngd[175]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/last, last, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:51 prngd[176]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/lastlog, lastlog, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:51 prngd[179]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/vmstat, vmstat, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:04:51 prngd[181]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/ipcs, ipcs, -a, , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:19:42 prngd[220]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/w, w, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:21:25 prngd[222]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/last, last, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:22:16 prngd[224]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/lastlog, lastlog, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:24:49 prngd[227]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/vmstat, vmstat, , , , ): No such file or directory

192.168.8.195.34453:<25>Jan  1 00:26:31 prngd[229]: Failed to execl(/usr/bin/ipcs, ipcs, -a, , , ): No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to understand why prngd gives me such errors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, those errors are generated because in the prngd configuration file (/etc/prngd.conf) those file are used to generate entropy. It is clearthat if those files are not present on the device, prngd generate an issue.
To solve this, is sufficient to comment the lines related to the missing files.